# LISP: Why can't I use cons on an empty list?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to construct a unique list of elements by adding to an empty list, using the following code in LISP:

```
    ;;;MEMSET - return T if an atom is a top-level member of a set, else NIL
    ;;;This is needed for the makeset function
    (DEFUN MEMSET (ATM L)
        (COND ( ( NULL L) NIL )
              ( (EQL ATM(CAR L)) T )
              ( T    (MEMSET ATM (CDR L)) )
        )
    )
    (DEFUN MAKESET(SET1)
        (DO ((UNIQ ()))
            ( (NULL SET1) UNIQ) 
            (COND ( (NOT (MEMSET (CAR SET1) UNIQ))
                      (CONS (CAR SET1) UNIQ)
                  )
            )
        (SETF SET1 (CDR SET1))
        ) 
    )
```

This particular code results in NIL when I call (makeset '(a b b a c d b a)) - it should result in (a b c d), with no regard to order) - but it looks to me like it should be adding one atom from SET1 that isn't yet in UNIQ each iteration. Can you not add to an empty list declared in a do loop, or is there some other issue I'm having? By the way, I'm using clisp.

Comment: Please fix the title to be a truth. This may involve first finding the actual truth (by stripping away everything that is irrelevant).

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, please fix the code formatting: downcase, indentation, hanging parens. Emacs should help.

Comment: The short answer is that `(cons x y)` doesn't *modify* anything;  it *returns* a new cons-cell.  Afterward `x` and `y` are the same as what they were before.  The result is the new value that you want.  That means you need something like `(setq y (cons x y))`.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I realize the formatting is a little wonky. This is one of the first LISP programs I've written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Use proper formatting**

Please use a proper formatting when asking something about Common-Lisp. 
See for instance the first three pages returned by googling ["common lisp formatting conventions"](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=common+lisp+formatting+conventions&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Here is an example of conventional format applied to your functions:

```
;;; Memset - return T if an atom is a top-level member of a set, else NIL
;;; This is needed for the makeset function

(defun memset (atm l)
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        ((eql atm (car l)) t)
        (t (memset atm (cdr l)))))

(defun makeset (set1)
  (do ((uniq ()))
      ((null set1) uniq)
    (cond ((not (memset (car set1) uniq))
           (push (car set1) uniq)))
    (setf set1 (cdr set1))))
```

**2. Use primitive functions when possible**

Both your functions are primitive in Common-Lisp.

[`remove-duplicates`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_dup.htm#remove-duplicates) returns a list without duplicate elements, [`member`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mem_m.htm) checks if an element belong to a set.

**3. The error in your function**

If you still want to use your function, instead of `remove-duplicates`, here is the problem in it.

If you want to modify a list, you should use a function that modifies something. The `cons` functions builds a new pair but *does* not modify anything. So in your form `(cons (car set1) uniq)` you add a new element to `uniq` in the sense that you obtain a *new list* with `(car set1)` as first element and the elements  of `unique` as rest of the list, but this new list is immediately discarded because it is not assigned to anything.

You can change this either by using the macro [`setf`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/a_setf.htm#setf) to assign the new value to the local variable `uniq` in this way:

```
(setf uniq (cons (car set1) uniq))
```

or you can write the equivalent form, through the use of the macro [`push`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_push.htm#push):

```
(push (car set1) uniq)
```

Finally, note that your `cond` inside the `makeset` function can be replaced by the more terse `when`, resulting in this function:

```
(defun makeset (set1)
  (do ((uniq nil))
      ((null set1) uniq)
    (when (not (memset (car set1) uniq))
      (push (car set1) uniq))
    (setf set1 (cdr set1))))
```

Comment: also `unless` or replacing `do` with `(let ... (dolist (x set1) ...))`

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll look into how to format my code so it's more readable. I appreciate the example code you've written. This is one of the first programs I've written in LISP so I still have plenty to learn.

Answer (score 1):

All the updates can be done with the stepping forms in `DO`. No need for `PUSH` or `SETF`:

```
(defun makeset (set1)
  (do ((uniq nil (if (memset (car set2) uniq)
                      uniq
                    (cons (car set2) uniq)))
       (set2 set1 (cdr set2)))
      ((null set2) uniq)))
```